# How to use Bind an Associative Swift enum?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `GroupView` that accepts a binding as a parameter because I want the GroupView to modify the data in the enum.

Can some help me on how to accomplish this?

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GroupView(group: /* What do i put here? */)  // <----------------
        }
    }
}

struct GroupView: View {
    @Binding var group: Group
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}

class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var instruction: Instruction!
    init() {
        instruction = .group(Group(groupTitle: "A Group struct"))
    }
}

enum Instruction {
    case group(Group)
}
struct Group { var groupTitle: String }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this certainly will work... but probably there's a better approach to your problem. But no one is in a better position than you, to determine that. So I'll just answer your question about how to pass a binding.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            GroupView(group: viewModel.groupBinding)
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var instruction: Instruction!

    init() {
        instruction = .group(Group(groupTitle: "A Group struct"))
    }

    var groupBinding: Binding<Group> {
        return Binding<Group>(get: {
            if case .group(let g) = self.instruction {
                return g
            } else {
                return Group(groupTitle: "")
            }
        }, set: {
            self.instruction = .group($0)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this compile?

Comment: Ah.. you moved if let inside the binding, i didnt realize nice!

Comment: Yes, the Biding initializer gives you a lot of room to play ;-)

Comment: Can you return an optional binding and only show the group view if that is not nil and force the optional then? The Getter and Setter thing is cool too.

Comment: It should be possible. At first I though of using Binding<Group?>, but since the OP asked about Binding<Group>, I left the answer as is.

Comment: well, you're right. your code does compile. But it doesn't compile inside of a Stack as shown above. I'll mess with this answer some more. I'll return to mark this as correct  if there no neater way posted. Thanks much.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't compile inside a stack? My example is using a VStack. You just need to set the binding outside of it, and then remember to use the `return` statement. Or did I missed your point?

Comment: Apologies. I missed the return statement.

Comment: Sorry, one final change. I think this is the winner. The natural place to create the binding is inside the model, as a computed property ;-)

Comment: @kontiki i have looked at this example and have tried to make it work for my project here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57567487/how-to-use-bind-an-associative-swift-enum-array  Is it possible you also know the answer here? If not, then its ok