# How to use Bind an Associative Swift enum array?

Tags: swift, swiftui

My question is similar to this one -> [How to use Bind an Associative Swift enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57562392/how-to-use-bind-an-associative-swift-enum)

I have modified the example provided to be an array.
The `GroupView` accepts a binding as a parameter because I want the GroupView to modify the data in the enum. The difference between the original question and this one is that in this one, the enums are an array instead of a single one.

How to i extract a binding from the enums so that the `GroupView` can modify the enums correctly? 
Here is the modified code

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<viewModel.box.instructions.count) { index -> GroupView in
                let instruction = self.viewModel.box.instructions[index]

                return GroupView(v: ????) // How do i extract the binding here???
            }
        }
    }
}
struct GroupView: View {
    @Binding var v: Group
    var body: some View {
        Button("Hello: \(self.v.groupValue)") {
            self.v.groupValue += 1
        }
    }
}
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var box: Box!
    init() {
        box = Box(instructions: [
            Instruction.group(Group(groupValue: 10)),
            Instruction.group(Group(groupValue: 20))
        ])
    }
}

struct Group { var groupValue: Int }
enum Instruction { case group(Group) }
struct Box { var instructions: [Instruction] }
```

Comment: Hi. Is the array fixed in size? ForEach should not use ranges if the array can change at any time. Since beta 5 (explain in their release notes), the view won't update if the array changes.

Comment: Oh sorry i didnt know. The array is not fixed in size. It can change. I hope this does not mess up the answer..

Comment: Ok, let me rethink it then...

Comment: ok. yes, lets say the array size is fixed. Dont worry about the size issue, i can work on that my self. It should not be too difficult i think. I just want to know how to get this binding... Its hard.

Comment: @kontiki would the size issue vanish if you take the array out and after modifying assign the array to it's place (eg in an _ObservableObject_) again? And can you tell me the position in the [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_6_release_notes), since this would be a big limitation please. I can't find it in release notes 6:(.

Comment: @Fabian Not sure about you're workaround. You may need to test it. I updated the answer to include the release notes section where the fixed limitation is explained. Note that it talks about List, but I found it to be more or less the same with ForEach.

Comment: @kontiki thank you very much! The workaround probably won't help. So we just have to pass in the array directly I guess? :D

Comment: Yes, but then the problem is the array is not `Identifiable` and because it's an array of `enums`, and enums cannot be made `Identifiable` (AFAIK), you probably need to make it at least `Hashable`, so you can use `id: \.self` instead

Comment: @kontiki just to know, if i used `ForEach(viewModel.box!.instructions, id: \.self)`  instead of the range, this would get around the restriction correct?

Comment: It would, but only if `Instruction` were Hashable (which it isn't). If you eventually manage to make it hashable, then you need to rethink your Binding<Group> function... what a nightmare!

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I'm thinking that you might leave the range as it is and manage to make it work by calling objectWillChange.send() manually, when your array changes its size. That would probably solve the problem...

Comment: awesome. please include in your answer if this works. Might be able to help some other poor chap like me! I think i have enough to float with. Thanks a mil.

Comment: Sorry. It did not work. Runtime complains with: ForEach<Range<Int>, Int, GroupView> count (5) != its initial count (2). `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!

Comment: @Fabian I updated the code to work with non-fixed arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, if the array is fixed in size:

```swift
ForEach(0..<viewModel.box.instructions.count) { index -> GroupView in
   return GroupView(v: self.viewModel.bindingGroup(idx: index))
}
```

```swift
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var box: Box!

    init() {
        box = Box(instructions: [
            Instruction.group(Group(groupValue: 10)),
            Instruction.group(Group(groupValue: 20))
        ])
    }

    func bindingGroup(idx: Int) -> Binding<Group> {
        return Binding<Group>(get: { () -> Group in
            if case .group(let g) = self.box.instructions[idx] {
                return g
            } else {
                return Group(groupValue: 0)
            }
        }) {
            self.box.instructions[idx] = .group($0)
        }
    }
}
```

If your array is not fixed, you should consider this from iOS13 release notes:

> The identified(by:) method on the Collection protocol is deprecated in
>   favor of dedicated init(*:id:selection:rowContent:) and
>   init(*:id:content:) initializers. (52976883, 52029393)
>
> The retroactive
>   conformance of Int to the Identifiable protocol is removed. Change any
>   code that relies on this conformance to pass .self to the id
>   parameter of the relevant initializer. Constant ranges of Int continue
>   to be accepted:
>
> ```swift
> List(0..<5) {
>     Text("Rooms")
> }
> ```
>
> However, you shouldn’t pass a range that changes at runtime. If you use a variable that changes at runtime to define
>   the range, the list displays views according to the initial range and
>   ignores any subsequent updates to the range.

**Then, if your array is not fixed in size, you may need more code:**

As I mentioned in the comments. You cannot make an enum identifiable (if you can, please do tell how!). So the only alternative is to use `id: \.self` in the `ForEach`. But to do that, we need to make `Instruction` conform to `Hashable`.

Also, to get the binding, we need the index of its position. The solution here (findIndex), may not be the best thing performance wise, but I don't expect your Instructions array to have thousands of elements... so that should be ok.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.box.instructions, id: \.self) { (instruction: Instruction) -> GroupView in
                let idx = self.viewModel.box.instructions.firstIndex(of: instruction)! // I am assuming it will always return a value
                return GroupView(v: self.viewModel.bindingGroup(idx: idx))
            }

            Button("Add Instruction") {
                self.viewModel.objectWillChange.send()
                self.viewModel.box.instructions.append(Instruction.group(Group(groupValue: 123)))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct GroupView: View {
    @Binding var v: Group
    var body: some View {
        Button("Hello: \(self.v.groupValue)") {
            self.v.groupValue += 1
        }
    }
}

struct Group { var groupValue: Int }
enum Instruction: Hashable {
    case group(Group)

    static func == (lhs: Instruction, rhs: Instruction) -> Bool {
        guard case .group(let gL) = lhs else { return false }
        guard case .group(let gR) = rhs else { return false }

        return gL.groupValue == gR.groupValue
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        if case .group(let g) = self {
            hasher.combine(g.groupValue)
        }
    }
}

struct Box { var instructions: [Instruction] }

class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var box: Box!

    init() {
        box = Box(instructions: [
            Instruction.group(Group(groupValue: 10)),
            Instruction.group(Group(groupValue: 20))
        ])
    }

    func bindingGroup(idx: Int) -> Binding<Group> {
         return Binding<Group>(get: { () -> Group in
             if case .group(let g) = self.box.instructions[idx] {
                 return g
             } else {
                 return Group(groupValue: 0)
             }
         }) {
             self.box.instructions[idx] = .group($0)
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that side note. I will see how i can get around this.

Comment: Ok, so I updated the code to work with non-fixed arrays.